# Form builder disable select doesn't work for attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my model, :start_date is an attr_ccessor. This seems to prevent disabled: true from working. Another option I tried, :enable_blank, worked fine

```
<%= b.select :start_date, options_for_select(dates(b.object.proposed_start), selected: b.object.start), disabled: true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work:

```
<%= b.select :start_date, options_for_select(dates(b.object.proposed_start), selected: b.object.start), {}, { disabled: true } %>
```

See more in the Rails Apidocks:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select